# Mac OS X NSGlobalClickCount in Global Preferences

Tags: macos, plist

I was doing some snooping around and came across a Global Preferences plist file located at:

~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist

While looking around I came across an extra for NSGlobalClickCount currently my number is at 3604876

I'm wondering if anyone has any information about this, or if I'm the only one who has it.

Comment: FWIW, I don't see this key in any of my accounts or computers I manage.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be used by a certain app to track its trial period. (I'll refrain from mentioning which app in public.)